# Getting "java.lang.illegalArgumentException: invalid column data1"

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts, contactscontract

I need to add a contact in a contacts group. The group is added but the contact is not added in the group.
Here is my code. I think the exception occurs in

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID
```

but i don't know why.. Can you can help me please?

```
ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
        .newInsert(ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE,accountType)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME,accountName)
        .build());

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
        .newAssertQuery(ContactsContract.Groups.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID, 0)
        .withSelection(ContactsContract.Groups.TITLE + "=?", new String[]{grupo})
        .withExpectedCount(1)
        .build());

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
        .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,           
                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.StructuredName.DISPLAY_NAME, nome)
        .build());

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
        .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE,ContactsContract.
                   CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA1, mail)  
        .build());

ops.add(ContentProviderOperation
        .newInsert(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
        .withValueBackReference(ContactsContract.Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, 0)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID, 0)
        .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE,    
                   ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)
        .build());

try {
    resolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops);
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The person who wrote the method you're calling incorrectly decided to throw that exception if you passed in any data that it couldn't handle.  I'd recommend consulting the javadocs to see if there's an explanation there.

It's called checking pre-conditions; programming by contract.